# Clicked drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

When I click `menu` text that should toggle the `menuContent` the first time, it works as it shows the `menuContent` which is what is meant to be shown. However, after it shows it does not hide so the `display = block` does not go back to `display = none`.

I tried using a `show` value but it did not work so I used `display = block` instead in an `if` statement.

(By the way: `menu` = button that toggles text and `menuContent` = text that should be shown or hidden)

This is the JavaScript:

```
menu.addEventListener('click', menuClick, false);
menuContent.style.display = 'none'

function menuClick() {
    menuContent.classList.toggle('show');
    if (menuContent.style.display = 'none') {
        menuContent.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        menuContent.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

So the first part of the `if statement` worked but not the `else` part.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
menuContent.style.display = 'none'
```

should be

```
menuContent.style.display === 'none'
```

otherwise you're setting menuContent back to "display: none" again.

Remind '=' and '==='!

Answer (score 0):

`menuContent.style.display = 'none'` is variable assignment, not a test for equality. You need to use `===` or `==` (loose check).

So, you always end up in the first situation because you always assign it to a value.

Comment: Thanks it worked. What is the difference between `==` and `===`?

Comment: @tices `===` is more strict as it returns `false` if the expressions are of different types, for example `0==false` is true, but `0===false` is false.

Comment: Oh so for `===` it has to be in the same data type but not with `==` right? @RatajS

Comment: @tices Right, ye can find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality